# Update the image of azure container instance?

Tags: azure

Azure Container instances

This is the first time i use docker image
when i trying build and upload new version code and push in Azure **Container registries**
but if i want to apply new version code , i must restart **Container instances** by manual to apply new version code , it annoys me and is a waste of time
How to resolove auto restart or redeploy when i push new version code in **Container registries** in Azure ?

[this is log deploy azure of myself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr8uM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways to do this.

**AKR Webhooks**

I probably will approach this by looking at the [webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-webhook) in AKR.

Then, create a Logic App to receive the webhook call when a new image is pushed. [References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-webhook-reference).

In the Logic App, you can call one of the [Azure Container Instance APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/container-groups/restart?tabs=HTTP) to restart the container group.

You will need to consider the security of the Logic App, which can only be called by your AKR's webhook.

**CI/CD Pipelines**

Assume that you have used a CI/CD platform like Azure DevOps, where you can create build pipelines.

The pipeline can build and push the images to your AKR, then create a step to run [Az command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-update) to update the instance group.

I probably prefer the pipeline approach as I can see the history of what images have been released on the DevOps page.